# ASP.NET, Send data from a view to a controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I want to send data from a view to a controller. I did it as shown below but the value is null.
Using jquery, I create dynamic fields and automatically sum the data in it.
 I  want to send an input text data in append.
How can I do that?

**My Jquery code  :**

```
$(Wrapper).append('\
        <div>\
        <input type="text" class="register_input span3"\
        name="value" + Count +'" id="value' + Count + '"\
        placeholder="Enter the value" style="margin:0px 15px 20px 0px"/>\</div>');) 



 @using (Html.BeginForm("Example", "Example", FormMethod.Post .....)
{
       ...
    input type="submit" value="save" id="save" 

}
```

**My Controlller:**

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Example(String value )
{  
     string a = value;  
     //a is null  ......

}
```

Comment: It is working my answer for you ?

Comment: The `<input />` html element has to be nested inside the `<form></form>` element, because when you actually click the `<input type="submit" />` button, it's actually passing the `<form>` element and its content as a request. So you should probably append it through jquery in the form, instead of `$(Wrapper).append(...)` use `$("form").append(..)`

Comment: `name="value"` not `name="value" + Count +'"` The `name` attribute must match the parameter of your method.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMueckeYes I removed the Counts and the problem is resolved.You can write an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter string must be (value+count)

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Example(String value+count )
{  
     string a = value+count;  
     //a is null  ......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<input />` html element has to be nested inside the `<form></form>` element for this to work, because when you click the `<input type="submit" />` button, it's actually passing the `<form>` element and its content as a request. So you should probably append it through jquery to the form. So basically instead of

```
$(Wrapper).append(...)
```

use

```
$("form").append(...)
```

Or give an id to the form, so you just target that specific form element.

Comment: The input element is already in the form element but doesn't work